# Where to place a private method that shared by multiple Spring java config file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-java-config

I have several Spring Java config classes and they have same private method. Should I create the private method in each Java config class or do I have other options to avoid listing duplicate method. By the way, I have a CommonConfig.java class imported by all other config classes. Can I make the private method and place it inside CommonConfig.java?

By the way, all other Spring Java Config classes import CommonConfig like bellow.

```
  @Import({ CommonConfig.class, })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the method in CommonConfig.java class, do not make it private else the extending classes won't be able to use it.

If the implementation of that method is different as per the classes you can make an interface & declare that method in that.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Implementation of the method is same for all Config classes. Parameters are being passed in are same type, just have different values depends on calling classes. If I make the method public and place it inside  CommonConfig.java class, then it should be available to all other Config classes importing CommonConfig.java, correct?

Comment: your public method would be available to any code outside your class. If you want that method only to be extended by the subclasses mark the method as protected. Please accept the answer if it resolves your query.

Comment: I know that public method is available to everywhere in Java. What I am checking here is since I created a public method inside Spring Java Config class and try to make sure it is same as regular Java class.

Comment: yes the subclasses will be able to use that method.

Comment: @Import({
    CommonConfig.class,

})

Comment: The CommonConfig class is imported like above from other Spring Java config class.

Comment: I don't have a super class and subclass concept in my Spring Java Config files.